# What files should I clean up before creating a disk snapshot?

Tags: virtualization, cleanup

After setting up a new Ubuntu virtual machine guest, I like to take a disk snapshot so that I can restore to a working state in case I break something later on. I'd like to avoid snapshotting unnecessary files, so I always run `apt-get clean` beforehand.

What else might I be interested in cleaning up before taking the snapshot?

Comment: What are you using the VM for? Does it have a GUI? If yes, are you using it for internet browsing?

Comment: @Lekensteyn It's for typical desktop use, so I can pull up an unmodified installation when helping out others, and to provide a place to test out experimental configurations without putting my primary installation at risk.

Comment: You might want to check the question [What files and directories can be excluded from a backup of the home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/q/40992/6969)

Comment: As snapshots will need considerable space you may consider [cloning](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#cloningvdis) your fresh VM and play with the clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your programs, but I think that you can pretty much purge everything in `/var/cache/` and `~/.cache` and also delete your browser's cache or other programs like that.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what cruft there should be on a fresh installation apart from  the apt cache. I'd rather concentrate on uninstalling unneeded packages. In `synaptic` you can sort them by install size.