# Unable to backup two files

Tags: backup

I'm new to Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and did my first backup today, using the backup program that comes with the distro.

After the backup was finished, there was a message that the following two files could not be backed up, and that I should make sure I could open them:

/home/myname/.cache/dconf

/home/myname/.config/enchant

I found them in the file manager, but when clicking on them, I'm told I don't have the necessary permissions.

Is the backup non-functional because of missing these two files? What should I be doing?

Thanks!

Kate

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/346392/why-can-d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-dup-not-complete-the-backup-of-cache-dconf-and-gvfs

Comment: You can run a simple `sudo chown $USER: $HOME` to fix it.

Comment: That's basically because those files got created with `sudo` by their respective applications (`dconf` and `Enchant`), and they get regenerated every time the applications run. Don't worry about them, your backup is fully functional.