# I installed Lubuntu 32 bit on 64 bit system. How should I go about upgrading to 64 bit?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I already downloaded the 64bit iso. I just don't know what's gonna happen, is it gonna make a third partition on my disk drive (currently have 2, one Windows one Lubuntu)? Do I have to delete the current Lubuntu 32 bit? I'm completely new to this so I'm just checking so everything goes as smoothly and functional as possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new partition for installing lubuntu 64bits and you will have 3 different OS.

You also have the option of installing lubuntu 64bits on one of the partitions you have created (windows and lubuntu 32bits).

I suggest you installing it over the lubuntu 32bits partition as I understand that you want to replace your current 32bits installation with a new installation of Lubuntu 64bits.

The installation process will be the same you followed to install lubuntu 32bits.

Comment: If you elect to over install, be sure to backup /home, perhaps /etc if you manually edited system config files like grub or network. Also if you installed lots of apps from repository you may want to export list to make it easy to reinstall them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders and:http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: Yes exactly I want to install the 64bit OS on top of the 32bit one, to replace it as you say. So I just put it on my live USB and when it asks for installation I should select install over Lubuntu or something like that?

Comment: Not exactly. It will show the partitions of your hard drive, I don't remember now but maybe it gives information about what type of partition they are or what OS is installed in each partition (I'm not sure). My recomendation is: start the installation process until you get to the partition selection screen and see what it shows, the installation process won't start until you select where to install () so you will be able to take a look and if you are not sure cancel de installation. Maybe you get more info doing that.