# Dual Boot - Grub showing only "System Setup"

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, live-usb

I had Windows 7 dual booted with Ubuntu 14.04. Yesterday I ran 
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

and after installing everything and restarting, I only got Ubuntu's option in my Grub.

Checking in grub-customizer, I saw that Windows boot loader had been erased and as such decided to restore it using boot-repair via live USB.
Now the problem is using boot-repair in recommended settings gave the following error

```
grub-pc purge cancelled. Send this to mail...
```

I also tried accessing the drive via live USB, mounting and installing grub using the link
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).

This method was not allowing me to run boot-repair or grub-customizer in the mounted drive. It kept giving the error which was something like

```
couldn't identify the host
```

That only gave me a single "System Setup" option in Grub.

Right now, I have used the "Restore MBR" option of the boot-repair to restore Windows boot loader and I am directly booting into Windows now. I am not greeted with the GRUB prompt on booting.

I have spent my whole day in figuring out a solution but to no avail. Do I have no option other than to reinstall Ubuntu? Please help.

EDIT-1: Added [Boot-Info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24322508/)

EDIT-2: Added GParted's result

[image: GParted's result]

Here /dev/sda1 is Windows primary partition (C)
/dev/sda2 is secondary (D)
/dev/sda3 is dedicated to Ubuntu

Comment: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:

Comment: Right now, I am directly booting into my Windows. There is no GRUB prompt while booting.

Comment: You have a new UEFI based system, but Windows installed in the 35 yr old BIOS/MBR configuration with Windows type boot loader in MBR. You also show /grldr which usually is EasyBCD & the very old grub4dos. If you want help with EasyBCD, you should go to their forum. Otherwise reboot Ubuntu installer in BIOS boot mode, add Boot-Repair and install grub to MBR to dual boot.

Comment: @oldfred How to install grub to MBR. Is there any option provided in the boot-repair?

Comment: If you boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode, it should just auto install grub to MBR. In advanced options you can choose an operating system and drive and many other settings like full uninstall/reinstall of grub and get new kernel. Advanced options: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ You may want to unintall EasyBCD also.

Comment: @oldfred Is it possible that any part of this process could render me helpless in accessing Windows?

Comment: You do have full backup of Windows? And a Windows repair disk? One should never make changes to any system without the current version of that install's repair disk or with Ubuntu the live installer. And backup of all of your data. System knows if you have backups and then it works to fix without issues. When you do not have backups, it never works. :) or so it seems.

Comment: @oldfred No, I didn't have any backups. The thing is I don't really know how to make backups in case of dual booted systems and how to use, if they have been created to restore everything. I am a newbie to this stuff and had to install Ubuntu to fulfill my development needs.

Comment: Windows users normally do full image backups. With Linux it is easy to reinstall Ubuntu, so normally user data & configuration is all that is required. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2137439&p=12611710#post12611710

Comment: @oldfred I can see my Ubuntu partition mounted when accessed via Live USB. Do you have any idea as to whether I can back it up entirely?

Comment: If you can mount it you should be able to back up. Most of your data is in /home. But best to repair boot, so you can also export list of installed apps, so you can more easily reinstall everything you added to standard install. You may have some configuration data in /etc if you manually edited hardware configuration.http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Comment: Previously, I was doing my projects on Ubuntu. I have migrated these projects successfully to Windows using Git. I am kind of preoccupied with these projects and will attempt to restore the boot and Ubuntu after I finish them. Can I consult you when I attempt to fix these issues. Right now, I am putting everything on hold. You have been of incredible help. Hope more people could be like you.