# Dual boot Ubuntu/Windows emergency mode

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, recovery-mode

Almost every time I try to boot Ubuntu I get emergency mode screen as seen here:

[image]

I tried all options listed and nothing helps.
After randomly many reboot and/or force shutdown I manage to boot Ubuntu. How can I solve this?

My fstab looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=73afa7f9-6262-495e-b6a3-deda059da829 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=68294dbf-0922-49bb-9cf6-2b1fd89b45f8 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=750b0356-acad-4889-b95e-b9dd73f4151a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I am currently running 17.04. but had same problem in older versions.

The results of `fdisk -l` are:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 231.8 MiB, 243089408 bytes, 474784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 83.7 MiB, 87793664 bytes, 171472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 83.8 MiB, 87896064 bytes, 171672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 83.8 MiB, 87863296 bytes, 171608 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0002d83d

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048  199979007  199976960  95.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2        199981054 1953523711 1753542658 836.2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5        199981056 1949501439 1749520384 834.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1949503488 1953523711    4020224   1.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases, you have now an expired system. Better to back up your data, installed applications, /home and any settings in /etc you manually changed and do a new install of one of the fully supported versions. I prefer to use current LTS as main working install, but have an install of newest version, just to see what is changing. Also some things not necessary to backup. https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading Ubuntu to 17.10 Ubuntu boots without errors, for now...