# Can't update from official repositories

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 17.04, repository

I constantly get error when doing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Or when i try to install some application. Looks like something have been broken with repositories, but i restored `sources.list` from scratch several times and pointed it to different servers but no success.

Now my sources.list looks like (i switched to the main server):

```
  1 ###### Ubuntu Main Repos                                                        
  2 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe                        
  3 deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty main universe                    
  4                                                                                 
  5 ###### Ubuntu Update Repos                                                      
  6 deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main universe               
  7                                                                                 
  8 ###### Ubuntu Partner Repo                                                      
  9 deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner                           
 10 deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
```

When I do to update i get:

```
~ $ sudo apt-get update

Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe all Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Looks like it says that it couldn't find the link.

```
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
```

But as for me the link is valid and could be verified.

Am I doing something wrong? I just copied official repositories to the source list? Why it can't update and install apps using them?

```
~ $ lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

Comment: 17.04 has passed EOL - you need to upgrade to a supported release

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[17.04 reached the end of live](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

- [Backup all your stuff for example with rsync](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders/545676)
- [start a release upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) with `do-release-upgrade`