# apt update error. Release file missing

Tags: apt

So I recently ran into a problem while I tried to use the "sudo apt update" command.

Here is the complete console output:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' 
does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates 
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security 
Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
```

I have been using Linux for a little while but I am still a rookie, so what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't update from official repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998044/cant-update-from-official-repositories)

Comment: The 'Search' box on this site will save you time and frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly this error occurs when the repository in question doesn't have a directory corresponding to your distro's version.

A partial workaround that I employ is to go on the repo website, checking what version is the most recent and replace my distro's one by it manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` files. Then I update and this works well, no more errors and I can install repo's software.

However that error is suspect about Ubuntu's security updates and I do not recommand using this trick for them...