# Looking for backup tools

Tags: backup

I am looking for backup tools for Ubuntu Linux for personal use with below features:

1. GUI or CLI mode
2. Automatic scheduling

   3. Compression with password protection

Script can also helpful for me with raync and tar commands or any other. Kindly share or suggest.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ may be a helpful place to look.

Comment: I use rsync & cron for a copy which I do not really consider backup as not versioned. My rsync to various flash drives and some copies to DVDs of most critical data are my versioned backups. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto I only backup my data and some configuration files, but not Ubuntu as easy to reinstall. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders Best practice for Backups - theFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992