# How can I duplicate my Ubuntu disk?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image

I have Ubuntu 18.04.3 on a mechanical 500 GB drive.  I have added an SSD.  I installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 on the SSD. The SSD is sda and the mechanical disk is sdb. Both disks have the same number of sectors.

I have more than a year of changes to the system installed on the mechanical disk.

I want to duplicate `sdb` on to `sda`.  Is this possible?
If I boot `sdb`, will `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sda bs=2G` work?

Is there a simpler way to duplicate the installation?
I mostly want the apt and python packages to be the same.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd[ab]
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x87f0c3fe
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          409600   2506751   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *      2506752 212221951 209715200   100G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       212221952 279330815  67108864    32G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       279330816 976773119 697442304 332.6G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x49598911
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            2048    976656    974609 475.9M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sdb2  *       976896 352538623 351561728 167.7G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3       352538624 391600127  39061504  18.6G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb4       391600128 976771071 585170944   279G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Should be as simple as restoring from your backup. Backup should let you do a new install & restore list of installed apps & /home. And perhap some settings in /etc. Only if server apps (Web, database, etc)  installed may you also need those from /. https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc  If you do an image copy, you cannot reboot with both drives connected as duplicate UUIDs not allowed.

Comment: Thanks.  Try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488629/how-to-use-dump-and-restore-to-clone-a-linux-os-drive) by [starry-eyed-sysadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6358206/starry-eyed-sysadmin).

> ## How to use dump and restore to 'clone' a Linux OS drive
>
> You can find plenty of info online about using `dd` to clone OS drives.
>
> Don't listen! It's MUCH faster to use `dump` and `restore` because you only copy the data, rather than copying all the blocks (empty or not).
>
> #### Part 1: Know where your source and destination drives are in the device list
>
> ```bash
> lsscsi | grep sd*
> ```
>
> will show you a list of scsi devices and their associated letters. If you are lucky enough to be working with a hot-swapable box, then you can simply run that command before and then after you insert the drive--the newest device to show up is, of course, the drive you just inserted.
>
> #### Part 2: Prepare to dump
>
> 1. Safety tip: assign variables for the destination and source devices. (Also, if you are doing this more than once, variablization allows you to reuse the commands.)
>
>    ```bash
>    SOURCE=/dev/sdx DEST=/dev/sdy
>    ```
> 2. A note on the source drive (the one you are copying from). If you are copying the current OS drive, it will (duh) already be mounted. If you are copying a different drive, it actually doesn't need to be mounted.
> 3. Copy the partition table of your source drive out to a file:
>
>    ```bash
>    sfdisk -d $SOURCE > part_table
>    ```
> 4. Copy the part_table already stored in a file
>
>    ```bash
>    sfdisk --force $DEST < part_table
>    ```
> 5. Zero out the boot sector:
>
>    ```bash
>    dd if=/dev/zero of=${DEST}1 bs=512 count=1
>    ```
> 6. Make your filesystem (one partition at a time):
>
>    ```bash
>    mkfs -t ext4 ${DEST}1
>    mkswap ${DEST}2
>    ```
> 7. Take a look:
>
>    ```bash
>    parted $DEST --script print
>    ```
> 8. Copy the label of all non-swap partitions. Example:
>
>    ```bash
>    tune2fs -L "/" /${DEST}1
>    ```
>
> #### Part 3: The dump | restore moment
>
> 9. Make a directory to mount the destination device of the dump | restore. (As mentioned above, source device need not be mounted.)
>
>    ```bash
>    mkdir -p /mnt/${DEST}1
>    ```
> 10. Mount the destination device:
>
>     ```bash
>     mount -t ext4 ${DEST}1 /mnt/${DEST}1
>     ```
> 11. `cd` into the mount point:
>
>     ```bash
>     cd /mnt/${DEST}1
>     ```
> 12. Dump and restore:
>
>     ```bash
>     dump -a0f - /dev/${SOURCE}1 | restore -rf -
>     ```
>
>     (*dump flags:* `a`=autosize; `0` (zero)= start at block 0; `f` = file, `-` = stdout; *restore flags:* `r`=rebuild; `f`=file; `-` = stdout)
> 13. The `dump | restore` should take just a few minutes.
>
> #### Part 4: use grub to install a boot loader onto the cloned drive
>
> 14. Assuming you are copying an OS drive (i.e., a drive off which you boot a box), you need to install a boot loader.
> 15. Grub identifies disks as hd#, starting from 0 (NOT 1). The correspondence is easy: `/dev/sda` = `hd0`, `/dev/sdb` = `hd1`, etc.
>
>     ```
>      [root@drive-toaster /]# grub
>
>      grub> root (hd1,0)  # use correct number for your disk!  
>      root (hd1,0)   
>      Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
>
>      grub> setup (hd1) # use correct number for your disk!  
>      setup (hd1)   
>      Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... yes
>      Checking if "/boot/grub/stage2" exists... yes
>      Checking if "/boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
>      Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd1)"...  27 sectors are embedded.
>      succeeded
>      Running "install /boot/grub/stage1 (hd1) (hd1)1+27 p
>      (hd1,0)/boot/grub/stage2 /boot/grub/grub.conf"... succeeded
>      Done.
>
>      grub> quit
>     ```

Comment: This resulted in a not-bootable disk.  After an hour or so, I installed from the iso image.
Now, I have to dup the package installs.  I know about apt-clone.  That may work.  But, my experience to date is the manual method works better.