# I want to switch my ubuntu and my windows drives

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I have a dual boot with ubuntu and windows, windows in an SSD and ubuntu in an HDD, I want to switch them without having to reinstall anything. Also, I recently reinstalled ubuntu and had some problems, and somehow managed to delete windows boot manager and windows is not even appearing in grub.

[image: Windows HDD]

[image: Ubuntu HDD]

Comment: When you say switch drives, are you just wanting to boot Windows or reinstall Ubuntu on SSD & Windows on HDD? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i want to know if it's possible to copy and paste my ubuntu to my ssd, and my windows to another partition in my hdd, besides of fixing the windows boot

Comment: Not easily with UEFI as each partition has UUID & GUIDs. They cannot be duplicates and GUID must be in primary partition table, backup partition table & partition. If out of sync, you have major issues. With Ubuntu often easier just to do a new install & restore from your normal backup.  Good way  to confirm backup includes everything as you still temporarily have old install. Do not know about Windows.

Comment: I got this while doing the boot-repair, which, btw, didn't work :(
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9zFhhQnZ2j/?fbclid=IwAR3IV7PbEZcAONcx9lvDv7q_T_0AcTphuvGebNQLskG6rdWIr_uyJPh_UCY

Comment: I think this is one of the rare cases where Boot-Repair made things worse. You have two gpt drives. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt, but Boot-Repair thought Windows was BIOS as you are not showing an ESP with /EFI/Microsoft folder & .efi Windows boot files. You show two bios_grub partitions on sdb. And their total size is similar to a Windows ESP. But now you have sdb4 as the ESP. Do not know if Windows can use an ESP on sdb for booting Windows install on sda. But you need a Windows repair flash drive and boot it in UEFI mode. And remove all bios_grubs and repair Ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: since i didn't understand a thing (i'm noob at this), i think i might just have to format my windows drive :'c or do you think i should even try? XD

Comment: Do you have good backups of your data? From both Windows & Ubuntu? Can you try Windows repairs, but I do not know details on fixing Windows.

Comment: yes, i have everything in sdb1, i just have installed programs in the OS drives, so yeah, i guess i'll lose my windows haha

Comment: You should have backups of /home, your data, and list of installed apps. https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc I also edit a couple of files (grub) in /etc, so I copy those into /home, so they get backed up. I use resync to another drive & multiple flash drives. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: I ended up just deleting windows and copying my ubuntu to the SSD :v thanks for everything 

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting windows and switching completely to ubuntu, to swap the drives i just used Gparted to copy and paste every partition related to ubuntu to the new drive.