# How to back up the whole Ubuntu and after installing windows, install the Ubuntu backup along the windows again?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, backup

so installing windows along ubuntu is not the best option as far as I know and I don't want to loose my current ubuntu

So Is there any way to back up the whole system and after installing windows, install the back up alongside it?

(By the way I have hybrid hard drive)

Comment: Depending on what you want to use Windows for, a virtual machine might be a valid option. This will allow you to keep you machine as it is and not have to deal with the hassle of dual-boooting.

Comment: @Matigo Actually I want to install windows for gaming, so unfortunately I don't think that a virtual machine would be the best option

Comment: I personally would use Clonezilla.

Comment: Use [Disks](https://www.maketecheasier.com/backup-hard-drive-gnome-disk-utility/). It has a facility for making Linux system images and I've always used it regularly to back-up and (sometimes) restore my system. So easy to use and it's never let me down yet.

Comment: UEFI/gpt or BIOS/MBR? You can only restore to same configuration easily. And then you need to install Windows in that boot mode. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt and only in BIOS mode from MBR using a primary NTFS partition with boot flag. Best to update your normal backup which should include /home, and list of installed apps. Perhaps system settings in /etc, if you changed those and if server apps those folder in / (root). http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Comment: Clone Ubuntu to an empty disk using dd. Install Ubuntu next to Windows using a Live USB and the `Something else` option. Plug in the Ubuntu clone disk and use GParted on the Live USB to overwrite the new Ubuntu root partition with copy paste from the cloned root partition. Confirm that UUID's from clone still match those in `fstab` and `grub.cfg`.