# How do I migrate my Ubuntu 18.04.5 Installation to my New machine

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Ubuntu. i need to know how can I back up my current installation for reinstall on my new machine without losing my Settings and applications.

Comment: Is that what you want https://askubuntu.com/q/9135/1051814 ?

Comment: I always suggest new install & restore from your normal backup. You do have a backup in case hard drive fails and you then have to do a new install? Backup should include list of installed apps as link in comment above, all of /home and your data if in other partitions. You may want some /etc files but if different hardware not all of it. And if server apps, you want to backup those folders in /, but do not need the rest of /. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Answer (score 0):

### Using dd to Clone File System from Old Drive to New Drive

- Create Live Ubuntu USB and Boot it.
- Plug in Target drive, (must be at least as large as Source drive).
- Open Gnome-Disks to confirm drive designations, sda, sdb, etc.
- In Terminal run `sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy`

  Where `sdx` is the Source drive and `sdy` is the Target drive. **Double check that the Target device designation is correct, one typo can overwrite your OS.**

  Some people prefer to add a block size, such as `bs=256k`, but I do not bother.

  **The process may take a long time without showing activity.**

  Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/bkupsavefiles-60904/index.html