# Screwed up badly enough to warrant wiping my SSD and fresh installing. Seeking help to at least do this correctly

Tags: partitioning, python, ssd, data-recovery

I've been trying to download some data science packages within my Ubuntu OS using Docker and noticed I somehow had used close to 150GBs of space. I tried this installation multiple times, so I thought this might be due to duplicate files. I downloaded FSlinter to remove duplicate files. It removed 5gigs but also somehow also screwed up my python and package manager. I can see I have the anaconda3 directory but entering 'pip' on the CLI returns the error of 'pip isn't found'. I only use Ubuntu for data science, and most all of my files are on GitHub, so this isn't a total loss. I still haven't determined where all my storage space has gone to, so I think a system wipe/reset is my best option.

I'm currently duel booting from Windows. Is there a safe and easy way to wipe all the data from this SSD (without wiping the windows portion of the drive it shares storage with) and start from a fresh install? Any help at all is appreciated, I'm pretty upset with myself for being so careless with downloading packages and deleting files.

Comment: You can just use Something Else and choose same partition for / and same partition for /home or other partitions. If you check format as ext4, that will erase old data & overwrite with new install. Backup anything in /home, or you list of installed apps before reinstalling. And if your Docker stores data in /, you also want to back that up. You may not need or want any or all of it, but best to have it backed up, just in case. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Comment: Can you run GParted, take a screenshot and post it in your question? If you have more than one drive then a shot for each drive, will help us understand your system better.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is probably using up your disk space.

You can run

```
docker ps -a
```

to see all container, including stopped ones.

Also have a look att the docker prune commands that makes it easy to remove unused images and containers.
https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/