# How can I change my system from HD to the SSD without reinstalling or reinstall but mantain configs

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

So, I do have an SSD (256GB) and my current Ubuntu system is placed in my HD (1TB). I was wondering if there is a way to move my system from the HD to the SSD without reinstalling it so i dont lose all my configs. That said, if there is no way of doing it without reinstalling it, how can I maintain my configs so that I can copy my system when reinstalling it?

Im running Ubuntu 20.04

Edit: as asked in comments, here is a screenshot of my `lsblk` output:

[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nutQo.png)

Comment: Could you update your question with `lsblk` command output or GParted  screenshot with HDD partitions?

Comment: What's on the `sdb` ssd now, and do you want to save it?

Comment: I dont really know what is sdb ssd but i dont want to save it. My old windows was there, but i dont really care about it.

Comment: you cannot have duplicate UUIDs, so best not to clone. While not what you asked, better to just do new install and restore from your backup which should include all your configurations. Most data & user settings are in /home. You can also export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall them. If you edited some system configs, those are in /etc. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders Also becomes good test that backup has everything as you still have old install. That would be important when you have a drive failure.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make your partition on which Ubuntu is installed smaller so that it would fit on your SSD.
You would have to copy your /boot partition to the SSD. Then your / ( root ) partition. You can do this with GParted. 
 Be aware that this could lead into dataloss. 
 I always seperate my documents ( /home ) from my OS, no matter what OS I'm running. So I can reinstall my OS without losing any data.