# Systemd freezing execution after grub boot on Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I am getting this systemd freezing execution status on my Ubuntu 20.04 / Windows 10 dual boot setup with the following errors:

[image]

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 installed, and I can boot into Windows without any errors.

I researched about this and read a article here that said my HDD is dying, which might be true as it's 4 years old, I tried going into recovery mode, but it showed the same error. Then I used a live USB and booted into it and ran `fsck` on the original Ubuntu partition and it didn't give any errors. I also tried mounting it and it actually got mounted as well and I was able to access my files, so I think the partition is perfectly normal, but I just can't boot into it.

Do you have any solution to fix these errors or should I just copy all my files into a fresh Ubuntu? Also please suggest me a tool to backup all my files and application data on the Ubuntu partition.

Comment: Backup is very important. You should backup /home, maybe some settings in /etc and export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. If data in separate partition(s) you need to back that up also. Ubuntu is relatively easy to install, so no reason to backup system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders  I use rsync but backup to multiple devices & use DVDs for critical data.

Comment: @karel nope, I can find ubuntu in grub and the above errors only came when I try to boot into it.