# Can I prevent my time consuming backup command from being interrupted by system suspension due to inactivity for a period?

Tags: suspend, backup, power-management

I am using XFCE power manager. Under System tab, for System Power Saving part, I choose System Sleep Mode to be: suspend  when inactive for 1hr when Plugged in. The maximum inactive time length is 6 hours.

If I am running a command to back up my home to an external drive, such as

```
sudo rsync -a /home/tim  /media/tim/externaldrive/  2>rsync-errors
```

which can take more than 10 hours, and I leave my laptop alone and go to sleep, will my Ubuntu be suspended one hour after I leave my laptop, and therefore interrupt the backup command?

If yes, how can I prevent my backup command from being interrupted, without changing System Sleep Mode?

Thanks.

Comment: This was also asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264745/212783)

Comment: Moving the slider most left gives `Never`.

Comment: While not answer to question, your first backup may take a long time, but then you should only be updating changes. I use `rsync -aruvlP --delete` and the -u parameter only copies changed files. See `man rsync`. Then subsequent backups are only new files. You also may want to exclude a lot of temp, cache & misc files.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Answer (score 2):

**1) systemd's inhibit**

Using systemd's inhibit for a single process can be accomplished by running

```
sudo systemd-inhibit --what=idle:sleep:shutdown:handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch --mode=block rsync -a /home/tim  /media/tim/externaldrive/  2>rsync-errors
```

`systemd-inhibit` requires elevated privileges. The invoked command was run as root on my system. For additional options see either [Systemd-inhibit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-inhibit.html) or run `man systemd-inhibit`

**2) [logind D-Bus API](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind)**

The logind D-Bus API and [Inhibitor Locks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) can be used in developing an app that properly issues and releases inhibitor locks.

**3) Presentation mode**

xfce4-power-manager gui includes an option called Presentation mode. It will; turn off DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling) so your screen won't blank or sleep, and prevents screensaver mode from activating.

Answer (score 0):

Update rsync to query the user prior to starting the back up to either remind the user to do the
"sudo systemd-inhibit --what=idle:sleep:shutdown:handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch --mode=block rsync -a /home/tim  /media/tim/externaldrive/  2>rsync-errors"
themselves or do it automatically.