# Inhibit suspend and hibernate until process terminates

Tags: suspend, hibernate, bumblebee

I've managed to get bumblebee + bbswitch + nvidia drivers configured after a bit of toil.  The remaining issue is whatever I run with optirun seems to hang up after resume from suspend or hibernate, and I can't unload the nvidia driver and power down the discrete card until reboot.  A nice temporary solution is to inhibit suspension and hibernation when I'm using the discrete card.

So far, I've got a little wrapper that invokes `optirun "$@"` and loops moving the mouse with xdotool until optirun terminates.  This does the trick, but I don't want to prevent the screen from dimming.  I'd like a solution to prevent suspension and hibernation ONLY, hopefully avoiding anything involved with gconf or writing config files.

Comment: Take a look at [systemd's inhibit](https://askubuntu.com/a/973399/723193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick (thanks to J. Starnes' comment)

```
#!/bin/sh
systemd-inhibit --type=sleep --mode=block optirun "$@"
```