# Rsync copying excluded directories

Tags: command-line, filesystem, backup, rsync, clone

## Background

I am trying to make a very comprehensive backup of my Ubuntu system. I am running the following `rsync` command:

`sudo rsync -aAEHSXxv --progress --delete --exclude={/home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup/*, /home/*/.cache/*, /home/*/.local/share/Trash/*, /dev/*, /proc/*, /sys/*, /tmp/*, /mnt/*, /media/*, /lost+found} / /home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup`

Where the file structure should be pretty evident.

## Problems

1. I get the following output regarding non-existent files/directories:

   ```
   rsync: change_dir "/home/*/.cache" failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: change_dir "/home/*/.local/share/Trash" failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/dev/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/proc/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/sys/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/tmp/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/mnt/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/media/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
   rsync: link_stat "/lost+found}" failed: No such file or directory (2)
   created directory /home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup
   IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
   ```

   Does this mean that file doesn't exist on the source or the destination? (Because they clearly exist on the source)
2. Later on, I start to get a bunch of entries regarding the `.cache` directory that I thought I excluded:

   ```
   ... 
   home/sterlingbutters/.cache/mozilla/firefox/90d4yr8z.default/cache2/entries/76A1426700B3173C5B976F65F04FA6CD01D90D15
   ...
   ```
3. I'm worried to "just see what happens" because if the directories aren't excluded correctly, I might end up with an infinite copy-loop since the destination directory is located at ~/.
4. My code almost exactly follows the patterns specified in [the docs here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#Full_system_backup) (the only changes I've made I feel should still be acceptable): 
   I also feel that my syntax follows that which I have found on other forum posts. Even if it didn't, wouldn't that pose a discrepancy between that and the docs in the link?

All help is appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: There should be no space after the commas in the exclude list, `--exclude={/home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup/*,/home/*/.cache/*,` etc.

Comment: Wow... seriously? That was it? Thanks

Comment: One bug. Please come back when you have tested the command, and tell us if it works or if there is some other bug too.

Comment: Working now, will let you know if any problems arise

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. Let us hope that it continues working, and performs the backup you want :-)

Comment: **@sudodus** Don't forget to answer if Sterling comes back and it works. **Sterling** Don't forget to accept the answer so the next person around know this works...

Comment: You can exclude a lot of temporary files. And then best to use a separate file list. Some files(temp, cache etc) to exclude from /home backup - post #8 by  Paddy Landau
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883834 and 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders and 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rsync` command line was almost correct.

There should be no space after the commas in the exclude list,

```
sudo rsync -aAEHSXxv --progress --delete --exclude={/home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup/*,/home/*/.cache/*,/home/*/.local/share/Trash/*,/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found} / /home/sterlingbutters/Butters-Ubuntu-Backup
```

Comment: Just want to see if I can avoid making another post: I want to backup the /run directory but rsync seems to ignore it, why is this even though its not listed in the exclude argument?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `/run` is a temporary directory, that you {need not/should not} backup. You can check the dates of the files there with `sudo ls -l /run`

Comment: Thats what I've read as well but some of the utilities (xauth to name one) I have been using are putting configuration data in the /run directory that i would like to preserve.

Comment: @SterlingButters, See [What is this new /run filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa); Anyway, it will be re-created at each boot/reboot, so it is not much to save. If problems with `rsync`, I think you can try to back it up with `sudo tar ...`, but if things change because of the backup during the backup, the result will not be quite OK. I think many backup tools skip `/run`.

Comment: You can add a lot of more folders inside your home directory, see my repo: https://github.com/rubo77/rsync-homedir-excludes