# Ubuntu 18.04 Backup to External Drive Partition

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, backup

I have a Ubuntu 18.04 on my system which has 200GB/256GB is used. I bought a external hard drive with 1 GB storage. I don't want to use it all for backup. Is it possible to partition the externl harddrive 256GB to backup and the rest to use for other data like a USB stick drive ?

How do I configure `Backups` app for this purpose to store the backups on that partition only in the hard drive? Also I want that partition on hard drive to be non visible to other PCs is that possible ?

Comment: yes, create a partition in the hard drive and If you are using some backup software the set the path to the partition where you want to store the backup otherwise if you do backup yourself then its super easy

Comment: I prefer rsync, but many alternatives. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem I created backup partition on sdb and used rsync to copy to that partition. Orginally simple script & but then added some system documentation & exclude some files. But that is not really backup but just a copy. Also then copy to several flash drives, so more of a backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997