# Unable to boot to Windows after downgrading Python on Ubuntu on a separate partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, python, windows

I accidentally downgraded Python outside of my environment on Ubuntu and it ended up corrupting both of my partitions somehow.

I get the following error when trying to boot to windows: `No partition active`  `error:file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found'`: [grub rescue mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4gcP.png)

I've done `ls (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/` etc for all the partitions to try and find the i386 file but it was nowhere to be found.

Manged to recover most of my important Ubuntu data by copying it to a new partition using my flash USB.
But I have no idea how to fix my Windows boot and it has lots of data, over 400GB. How could I boot to my good old Windows?

Edit: I have run the boot repair program that oldfred recommended via 2nd option on my Ubuntu boot. The resulting pastebin is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yFNSMpG9xN/

Comment: Be sure to boot live installer to run Boot-Repair in same boot mode as your installs. Either UEFI or BIOS. If drive is MBR(msdos) as shown and with Windows then it must be BIOS. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thank you for this. the pastebin is here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yFNSMpG9xN/

Comment: You have new UEFI hardware and Ubuntu now installed in UEFI boot mode. But Windows is installed the old BIOS boot mode which requires MBR(msdos) partitioning. UEFI wants gpt partitioning which would erase drive. You cannot have both UEFI & BIOS boot on same drive. Windows has to have its boot flag on its boot partition, your sda1, but created sda5 as ESP. Move boot flag back to sda1. Since two drives you technically can dual boot with NVMe as UEFI and sda as BIOS, but not from grub. If you convert NVMe from MBR to gpt that will erase drive, but UEFI prefers gpt.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what some of these terms mean here. So all I have to do is move the boot flag to sda1? Are there any other steps? How do I move the bootflag, can I do it from terminal

Comment: Used gparted to move the boot  flag to sda1 and I'm able to boot to windows now. Thanks

Comment: If system now working, make sure you have good backups. Then any issue does not become a major crisis. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997  & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: Aye, thanks for the links! I've set up Timeshift and making daily backups now. Lesson learned