# Automating use of dd in a bash script with a day of month variable

Tags: bash, dd

I want to automate a backup using dd in a bash script.

I currently use this command to create a backup image of my sda2 partition:

```
sudo dd bs=64K if=/dev/sda2 | gzip > /mnt/backup/backup_sda2_**TODAY**.img.gz
```

I want to parameterise  a bash script with a variable **TODAY**- where **TODAY** is the current DAY OF THE MONTH – so, for example **4th April 2021** will be **4**

So my questions are:

1.How do I create the variable **TODAY** using system date?

2.How do I build it into the dd command above?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use [`date +FORMAT`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) to get the current day (FORMAT would be `%d` in your case) and [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) (`$(...)`) to build it into your command:

```
sudo dd bs=64K if=/dev/sda2 | gzip > /mnt/backup/backup_sda2_$(date +%d).img.gz
```

Note, that `%d` is zero-padded:

> %d - day of month (e.g., 01)

Note, that this will backup the whole `sda2` partition including empty space. There are surely better options, e.g. Ubuntu's Déjà Dup tool (a.k.a. "Backups"), which is doing incremental backups.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr :D

Comment: Note that `%d` is zero-padded by default - if they *really* want "4th April 2021 will be 4" they'd need `+%-d` (although I don't recommend it - since it will make sorting of the generated files more difficult)

Comment: true, thanks, added a hint ;-) I only tested with 14^^

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. One question on dd- I normally do this via a live usb of ubuntu. But can I use the script above in a bash file on my actual system. I am new to Linux but I am guessing this means the partition  I want to backup (sda2) is still mounted?

Comment: Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997  Ubuntu is relatively easy to reinstall, so better to plan that & backup your /home & data, list of installed apps and maybe /etc.