# Can I use dd to back up a mounted partition?

Tags: dd

I usually use a live usb to back up a partition using dd (typically sda2). Can I do this while actually in my system ?

I am new to linux but wont the partition be mounted (the partition I am backing up is mounted on root)

```
sudo dd bs=64K if=/dev/sda2 | gzip > /mnt/backup/backup_sda2_020420_1.img.gz
```

many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dd` on a mounted partition but it won't be a good idea for a backup, and less if it is mounted at the root of the filesystem. As far as I know:

- `dd` is a low level tool that will copy the full partition byte-by-byte, including all "empty" space with no files, which may actually contain random or old data (in a HDD). For instance, a `dd` image of a 240 GB partition will be 240 GB in size, even is the partition has 200 GB of free space. You may get some compression with `gzip` but it may not work well enough.
- If the filesystem is being used while `dd` is running on the mounted partition, the image may end up in an inconsistent state with some corrupted files.

For backup, you'd be better with using `rsync` or some other file-copying or file-syncing tool.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but the whole idea of using a live session is to prevent someone or something writing to the partition while you are doing the disk dump. If there are changes the result is a disk dump that might not be the exact same. Mind also that a disk dump of the root system will also dump virtual filesystems. You normally do not want to dd those.

`rsync` might be a better option: `rsync` the 1st time takes all files but the 2nd time it will only copy differences. On the other system you only have to extract the differences.

---

If you add `pv |` (`pv` = pipe viewer) before gzip you get to see the progress of the dd commnand (`sudo apt install pv`).