# Replacing Hard Disk used for storage Ubuntu is on SSD

Tags: clone

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS installed on a SSD and two other hard drives I use for storage. I want to upgrade one to a bigger drive is there a way to clone it. I have a USB3 Hardrive dock as well.
I am a NOOB so any help appreciated and go gently
Cheers

John

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1. Create on the new drive the same partitions like your current layout. Then boot to live System and copie all from your old to your new, then I think you must reinstall grub and change the UUIDs in your fstab to the new UUIDs.
2. Boot live and clone with gparted the partitions to your new drive, maybe there you must reinstall grub too.

Comment: Live USB/CD are the best option, if on this partition who will cloned no file are used at the current system, it will work without, but if for example /home on this partition you should use a live system @user535733

Comment: This is like a backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools But when new drive is larger, you also may be changing from MBR(msdos) to gpt and then can only use data copy commands. I suggest then rsync, but cp -a also works. Create new partitions, mount them & give yourself ownership & permissions., so you can copy to them. Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition see simple backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync

Comment: Thank you for replies i copied files onto new HDisk and have now got it up and working in PC. I know have another issue where if I delete anything form the HD it is permanent. I've created a .Trash-1000 folder but still no luck will do some googling