# What is the best practice with backing up Ubuntu drive (20.04)?

Tags: backup

**Context**

I have my Ubuntu OS installed on a 120 GB SSD. I recently started backing up my drive on a separate mechanical HDD. I just have a single user for this Operating System.

**Structure**

I used the `Backups` application and have automatic backups scheduled each week. The only directory I am saving is: `/home/[username]`

I am saving this on the external drive which is mounted `/media/[username]/LinuxHDD` where I set all the backups inside a `Backups` directory. I also moved the default `lost+found` directory inside `Backups` since I read it was used for data recovery if the drive becomes corrupted: [lost+found information](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix)

Under folders to ignore I have `Trash` and `~/Downloads`

**Question**

- Does the current approach I have now follow good practices?
- Is it safe to move `lost+found` from its default location?
- Is there any way I can improve this backup schema?

Comment: I use rsync & exclude a lot of temporary or cache folders. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 I also edit a few files in /etc, but just copy those into /home, so backed up. If you install server apps, you may have folder in / (root) that need backup. And you should backup list of installed apps., http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: brilliant, thanks again! @oldfred