# Which files to clean/delete that arent needed when making a disk Image

Tags: command-line, bash, backup

Before I make an image of an installation, I wish to clear files that not neccessary, like old log files, files that are created at boot, so when I compress the image, it does not add a lot of uncessary baggage to the file size.

So far I performed the following:

- `swapoff` then delete the swap file
- `sudo rm -rf /tmp/*`
- `history -c`
- `sudo apt-get -s clean`
- Delete chromium data/cache

What else could one do? E.g. Is it safe to `rm -rf /var/log/*`?

Comment: That's completely dependent on what your are going to use the image for. You can delete all manually created users and all application and system cache directories as well.

Comment: @FedKad good point about system cache, I wish to keep all functionality, I create the image, test it, then wish to clean it.

Comment: Many of use just backup /home, data, list of installed apps and if any server apps those folders in / (root). It is then easy to reinstall Ubuntu & restore system. Some folders in /home that you do not need to backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Comment: @oldfred, the thing is, there is quite a bit to setup, I need to do it 13 times on 13 terminals.

Comment: @FedKad, by system cache directories do you mean `/home/user/.cache` dirs?