# Backup on Ubuntu with avoiding folder with particular names

Tags: 20.04, backup, deja-dup, alternative

I would like to do a backup periodically of my `/home` ""partition"" in cloud (Gdrive). The current back-up tool or program is used by Ubuntu to backup is Deja Dup and It doesn't support the ignorable files/folder.

I am a dev, and usually I put all my projects in a folder on a Desktop. Sometimes these projects contains the libraries and packages which I don't want to back up, i.e. node_modules, vendor, python_enviornment, someotherFolderName...

I am looking for a backup program/tool for Ubuntu in which I can tell the program to ignore the folder to back up with given name, so the tool must not back up the content of the that folder.

Comment: Create an exclude file like these examples and use rsync: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Comment: Dejà Dup supports excluding folders. The default settings exclude Trash and ~/Downloads. You can more if you want.

Comment: But I don't want to mention the absolute path. Just name of the folder.