# My Ubuntu doesn't boot even after boot repair because of repartition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I started using Ubuntu short time ago... Firstly when installing it instead of windows, I didn't format the whole disk...
I just formated the C partition and left the other ones with my personal data on...

Then I changed the C partition from NTFS to the Linux file system format (ext4, I think)...
BUT I didn't change the other two partions' format...

And I opened the OS and worked for it and it was all good... The system reads the two other partions as if they were usb...

Then I put a herin boot cd and repartitioned the windows partitions like I used to do before...

It all worked well... But when I tried to open the OS, it didn't boot... I searched and opened it manually then I used boot repair from live usb with Ubuntu...

It worked at first.. But when I tried `sudo apt update`, it gave me error...

Then I knew I should have installed the boot loader from ubuntu's repositories.. I figured it out ond it all worked well again...

Recently when I ran `sudo apt update`, there were lots of updates (as I didn't use the lap for a while)..
After it updated, it said that it needed to reboot to work well...

It couldn't boot again... Tells me this message...

[image: Photo of screen displaying error message]

I tried boot repair... It says that boot repair successfully but it shows the same message...

Here are the boot repair info..

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kpRTbXBV77/

Comment: What brand/model system? It looks like it is UEFI compatible but you have BIOS boot using MBR partitions. Since you are past grub and starting to boot it is an issue beyond Boot-Repair. Grub menu not normally shown with one install. And with BIOS you need to hold shift key from Lenovo logo until grub menu appears. Then see if you can boot recovery mode or second grub entry. You may have video issue. Did you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: With how scrambled your system is, it might be best to boot from a live USB, back up all your data, and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. There's so much going on here that it would likely be difficult to debug the exact problem(s) without physical access to your system or live chat support. That being said, the kernel panic you're getting suggests something's awry with the initrd.img file your kernel is trying to use. Check your GRUB configuration (it's in /boot/grub/grub.cfg).

Comment: lenovo thinkpad t540p i7 2015.... This is the model... Yes, I reinstalled grub many times before, at first it showed that the error is failed to read files from sector sda0.... But then after some reinstallations it showed the past message... Grub menu appears automatically without pressing any thing.. It doesn't enter recovery mode it stays long and show the message same as normal mode... It says loading linux generis.. Loading initial ramdisk... Then the error messagr appears...

Comment: Yes I installed nVidia from ubuntu software with GUI but I am not sure if it was compatible with my device... As I was -and still- quite new to Linux And I don't know if there video driver installed automatically with linux or updated with sudo apt upgrade...    @oldfred

Comment: @ArrayBolt3    What files and folders shall I backup -in details please or a link to a detailed article-?  Shall I do it with deja dup or there is other program?..... Is live chat supported on stack overflow?If not where? Is it free? ...   I checked the flie path and the folder boot is empty.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem  I prefer rsync of just my data, and list of installed apps (and maybe some system settings). http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 This may have since been fixed? T540 works but UEFI settings critical or it may brick reset w/ Switching "OS Optimized Defaults
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hFTArhNbmpmEBRkwRg0DMbEzLBCl43F1HXoXtJ8cm0k/edit?pli=1