# Recommended backup solution with recovery

Tags: backup

we are installing a Ubuntu 22.04LTS desktop and would like to apply a regular backup solution.

We are able to find several backup software to perform backups. But we would like to create a recovery plan (and test it ahead of time!!) for the case of a catastrophic failure of the main drive. None of the backup utilities seem to come with a bootable media that allows us to recover the most recent backup to a (new) hard drive. It is unlikely we are the only ones with this use case, so maybe someone has a recommendation of which backup solution to use?

The usual instructions is to boot a live USB and then install the backup software onto it - but we fail here (disk space issues, ram drives, not persistent changes etc).

Thank you.

Comment: Less downtime = More expensive solutions. How much downtime can you tolerate?

Comment: Perhaps you might explain your vision of recovery from a catastrophe, and then we can offer you solutions. For example, "I need to reinstall proprietary applications X, Y, and Z, and all the data from 15 minutes before the catastrophe occurred." or "My three users just need to be their LibreOffice documents stored in their /home, and they can lose up to one days' work."

Comment: What "usual instructions" ask you to boot a LiveUSB for routine backups or restoration?

Comment: I have used my backup to install to a new system. I just use rsync to copy /home, data partitions, list of installed apps & maybe some settings in /etc. I then just do a new install & restore data & reinstall apps automatically from the list. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Comment: Congratulations on wanting to TEST your backups! There are at least 4 classes of "things to backup/restore": 1) System software; 2) Configuration data; 3) Added software; 4) User data; They should each be planned for. `rsync` is the tool of choice. Read `man rsync` and see `https://rsync.samba.org/examples.html`. Consider building a Live USB with the backup software installed.

Comment: There is no particular downtime requirement. Just able to easily restore the whole system as it is after purchasing another copy of the same (or larger) drive.

Comment: When it comes to making our own bootable USB stick, most (all?) instructions assume we already have an ISO file. Where do we get one that contains backup software.