# can i make an image file of a standard Ubuntu 20.04 ? not DD with a lot of parameters, but a GUI program, please

Tags: backup

For Windows there are plenty of image/ISO creating programs, I haven't seen any in Linux yet ?

Comment: Most CD/DVD writing apps in Linux can create ISO files. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1418370/edit) and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and add information on what you have tried so far. [Edit] your question title and remove the extra sentence; any detailed information should go the question _body_ and not the _title_!

Comment: "I haven't seen any in Linux yet ?" the 1st 5 that appeared on google when I searched do have the ability. What programs did you check and discard? Otherwise you will get answers including what you already checked; seems a waste of our time :)

Comment: Also: https://clonezilla.org/, but an image is not a backup as you probably will not refresh if often and it is out of date after just a few minutes of using system. You may want to think about rsync or grsync. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync#Grsync  You can easily reinstall Ubuntu & restore your data, and a list of installed apps. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Comment: Have you tried Timeshift?

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called "Disks" in Gnome that can make an image of a disk
You just need to

- Open disks (or install from the store if you don't have it)
- Select a disk you wanna make an image of
- Click the 3 dots
- Click Create Drive image (or something similar)

Answer (score 1):

### Make an image file of a standard Ubuntu 20.04

Besides for **dd** and **Gnome-Disks** Ubuntu image/ISO creating programs include **mkusb**, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb, **Ventoy**, https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy/releases, **Etcher**, https://www.balena.io/etcher/.

Etcher is a Live only boot disk maker, mkusb and Ventoy will make persistent USB drives. (mkusb is simplest to use).

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926