# how to exclude the multiple directory in rsync?

Tags: scripts, backup, rsync

Could someone please suggest how to exclude the multiple directories . The below mentioned code here i am trying to exclude the logs , but the code is not working.
I have to exclude the logs directory alone as well as another folder called packages which resides inside /home/ec2-user/source/IntegrationServer/instances/packages

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/home/ec2-user/source
dest=/home/ec2-user/destination

rsync -arv --exclude '/home/ec2-user/source/IntegrationServer/instances/default/logs/' $source/ $dest
```

Comment: I prefer a file if more than a very few exceptions.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders &  http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory/37219769#37219769

Answer (score 10):

just add (--exclude) multiples times

```
rsync -av --exclude some/subdir/linuxconfig --exclude some/other/dir --exclude exampledir /path/to/src/ /path/to/dest/
```

Comment: You can also use `--exclude-from` and list names of directories to exclude in a file.

Comment: Also think about shell parameter expansion! `rsync -av  --exclude={'some/subdir/linuxconfig','some/other/dir'}`