# How to backup settings/data as part of a reinstall

Tags: dual-boot, backup

Planning to reinstall to latest LTS release to allow repartitioning of dual boot (made Ubuntu partition too small and get repeated warnings that I'm running low on space--fwiw, not possible to simply adjust via gparted to provide more disk space to Ubuntu partition).

Generally happy with my system config, so wondering which files/settings/etc should I save/backup to allow as seamless a transition as possible to new version.  I wouldn't be updating unless I wanted to repartition to give more space to Ubuntu since it's my daily driver, so would ideally be running a near identical system after repartition and reinstallation.

Guidance as to the 'how' both before and after reinstall is appreciated as well.

Comment: You want /home which has all user settings, list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall, and perhaps some settings in /etc. I only edit grub, so just copy those changes into /home so backed up. If server apps, you may need those folders in /. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup your home directory with rsync and skip useless folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders)