# Backup files in Ubuntu, no /var directory

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I accidentally deleted my /var file and thus want to uninstall and install ubuntu again. I tried to install timeshift, Deja-dup and duplicity through apt in order to back up my files before I uninstall ubuntu. However, I always get the `unable to locate package` error. Can anyone help me find a solution for this? Is there any backup software that is automatically installed with ubuntu 20.04.4?
Thank you.

Comment: Wrong and nonsensical approach. First of all you should have backups no matter what. Having those and everything else is a moot point. Assuming you don't have backups you can do then right now from a live session and even, from the same live session, reinstall the OS entirely **without formatting** the root partition or /home partition if separated. All you'd need to do after that is reinstall any manually installed software.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with your running system? You need to use live installer. I prefer to backup /home & list of apps. The list of apps needs to be from a working system, but you should be able to backup /home with rsync. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 You can do an install without reformatting. That keeps your files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So what exactly is a live installer/session, and how do I do it? I google it but couldn't find much information. I am sorry for the question, I am a newbie around here.

Comment: A *live installer/session* is the original USB you used to install Ubuntu. It's the "Try Ubuntu" environment on the installer.

Comment: This seems a classic [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your REAL problem is that you have deleted your /var directory. Your preferred alternative is to reinstall Ubuntu (understandable). This has led you down an unreasonable path to believe that you need deja-dup and duplicity in order to create some magical "backup". No -- you need to preserve your data: Your e-mail, your work, your photos. There's no magic: You simply copy them from your /home directory onto some other media. If you are truly a "newbie" then there might not be much to preserve.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I just don't know where to copy them though, because I don't know which media or directories will be deleted when I uninstall ubuntu...

Comment: @user535733 do you have any advice about where to copy the files? I guess it has to be to some windows folder but don't know exactly which one or how exactly to do it?

Comment: Shall I do something like: scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/Name/Desktop

Comment: Were I in your shoes, I would choose a different media entirely, one that is not on the same hard drive at all. An external disk, a USB stick, a DVD-RW, a cloud directory, a directory on a different local machine, etc. A mistake with an installer can wipe your entire hard drive. Choose whatever is most convenient for you. A media and copy method that you understand. It would stink to waste an hour copying all your data onto a different location in the same hard drive...then erroneously wipe that entire hard drive anyway. Almost as bad is when you can't figure out how to copy the files back.

Comment: @user535733 I am in not particularly confident in any copying method. I was thinking of copying them to a bucket on google cloud and restoring them afterwards. Would you advise me to do so? I don't know much about google cloud so I don't know if it even works or not...

Comment: If that's a method of copying that you understand, that you can access the backup from a different machine, that you are comfortable with, then it's the right method for you.