# Necessary things to do after Ubuntu Installation on Laptop

Tags: wine

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop and wanted to know what are the necessary things to do after Installation. Also, I have tried installing Wine for Windows it is only able to run Whatsapp no other .exe files are not running.
PFA Screenshot of my laptop configuration

[image]

Comment: Welcome to AU. The question 'What to do after an Ubuntu installation?' is subjective, and therefor it has no answer. Look on Youtube e.g. what you CAN do after installation. You can edit your question into 'Why does Wine ( mention version ) only running Whatsapp and no other exe. files?' . Post the configuration as code, not as photo.

Comment: you may find this article from It's FOSS helpful: https://itsfoss.com/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: There are no general "things to do after installation". You can start using the system right away and gradually customize it to your needs. For me personally (but it's definitely subjective) one of the first things is installing Synaptic Package Manager, as it makes installation of software much easier (for me), and configuring updates to be installed only after I manually accept the prompt to install them (no automatic update installation). But these are just my preferences. In 22.04, I would also probably immediately replace snap Firefox version with .deb version.

Comment: Backup. I prefer to backup data, configuration, and list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall any apps I added. I can easily reinstall & restore from backup. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery & http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997 &

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you what is required because I don't know your situation. I can suggest a couple of things considering it's a laptop (as opposed to some other form factor).

Laptops are portable. If you take them out of the house, you don't have level one of physical security (fences, gates, walls, doors, etc.) This means you should consider levels two (e.g., a lock and cable) and three (passwords, encryption, etc.) even more important.

Suggestions:

- A BIOS password might be a good idea
- Don't add a root account
- Make sure your `sudo` password is strong
- Don't use automatic login
- Use full-disc encryption, or at least encrypt `/home`
- Use a "cloud" service that offers end-to-end encryption, or use [Veracrypt](https://veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) and/or [GNU Privacy Guard](https://www.gnupg.org/) for files you need to move around
- Consider a VPN
- Learn to configure your firewall well

Also, considering it's a battery-powered thing, look into [Laptop Mode Tools](https://www.unixmen.com/laptop-mode-tools-extend-laptop-battery-life/).

Answer (score 0):

"*What are the necessary things to do after Installation?*"

## Nothing. Just use it.

Ubuntu is a COMPLETE and SAFE general-purpose desktop environment for most users. You can have a great experience with the stock install and the included Ubuntu Software application.

Clickbait sites want you believe that they have some secret knowledge to share. They don't.

- If you have data that you value, you might look into backing it up. A great backup application is included with the stock install of Ubuntu.