# Some way to create an installable ISO from an installed (and customized) Ubuntu system (22.04 Jammy Jellyfish)?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, iso, customization, live-cd

Any help as soon as possible would be greatly appreciated.

I customized Ubuntu very deeply, everything from the OS release file to the wallpaper, shell themes, custom Plymouth theme, logo in the about page, everything, you name it, with the goal of creating my own psuedo-distro, called EklonOS. However, I'm having trouble turning it into an installable ISO. I tried a tool called Penguin's Eggs (https://github.com/pieroproietti/penguins-eggs), that worked for me in the past with customizing KDE neon, however, when I tried it now, when I burned the ISO to a USB and booted from it, the live desktop was exactly customized where I wanted it, but when I ran the installer, I ended up with regular ubuntu, with a blank blue wallpaper, all the apps installed, but none of my shell themes or customizations. I also tried Distroshare's Ubuntu Imager program, but it failed, apparently because the ISO file generated would be too big (larger than 4 gigabytes). Is there any other program I can use to generate an installable ISO file from this? I’m **not trying to make a backup for myself,** I’m trying to create a live ISO that can be used by someone else to install a copy of my (customized) system.

Thanks so much, and any help as soon as possible is needed and appreciated.

Comment: Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: No real reason to create ISO. And as image file it is obsolete as soon as you start using system. All desktop user settings are in /home. If server apps those may be in / and should also be backed up. You can export list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall. So if you do a new clean install, and restore from your backup, you have your install again. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Comment: Yes, but how would I distribute that? I was planning on distributing the ISO on my website, just like Ubuntu and every other distro. Users would then download and install normally, but with all the custom setting. I’m not just trying to make a backup for myself.

Comment: And there’s also things like the custom Plymouth theme and the edited OS-release file that I want to be the way I have them set up out of the box