Ubuntu Server OS ISO backup
I am new to the Ubuntu Server OS and I am running the latest version of it installed on a 500GB NVME drive. I have spent a lot of time building my OS. Therefore, I want to protect my work by performing a complete end to end backup of the entire OS.
Ideally, I would like to create an ISO backup file of my entire Ubuntu Server OS and have the ISO file end up written to an external USB hard drive.  What is the correct software tool to use for creating such an ISO file?
If that option is not possible, I was thinking of cloning the 500GB NVME drive using a NVME cloner such as the one shown in the link below?
Sabrent Offline NVME Cloner
However, I have concerns this cloning approach will create UUID differences between the source NVME drive and the cloned target NVME drive. Is this a valid concern?
Or is it better to use an app like Timeshift to accomplish this task? If yes, can TimeShift even run on the Ubuntu Server OS in the same way it runs in Linux Mint OS? And can it create an ISO file and save it to an external USB drive?
I welcome and advice relating to what is the best approach to use for accomplishing this task.

Timeshift is not suitable for this. Your best bet is to read up on Clonezilla. In summary you make a bootable usb key containing a live version of Clonezilla. You boot it. Then you can create a complete backup of your server on any suitable storage device

Any image type backup is obsolete the minute you start using system again. One users history: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482329&page=2&p=14124545#post14124545 & his backup.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462752&p=14040507#post14040507 Files to exclude: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders &
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to make an EXACT ISO of my system to put on other computers?
